# PostgreSQL Select statement with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I'm fairly new to SQL selects and I am attempting to select from multiple tables to show all results from the `sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants` table with columns from other tables appended where there are matching values. If a match isn't found that's OK as long as it shows null and `sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants` are not omitted or duplicated. Below is some code I have attempted. In addition I have tried using some left outer joins without success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.projectnum,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.projectnumother,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.projecttitle,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.projectother,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.annual_inspect,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.inspect_date,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.past_assistance,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.public_rec,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.park_maintained,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.lwfc_sign,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q1a,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q1b,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q2a,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q2b,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3a,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3b,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3c,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3d,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3e,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q3f,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q4,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q5,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q6a,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q6b,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.q6c,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.attest,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.attestdate,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.localcontact,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.regconname,
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.regcontitle,
tbl_lwcf.status,
tbl_lwcf.grantee,
fc_nc_counties.name_locas,
fc_nc_counties.rrs_regions

FROM
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants,
fc_nc_counties,
tbl_lwcf,
fc_lwcf_grant_boundaries,
fc_lwcf_grant_points,
fc_lwcf_rrs_regions

WHERE
tbl_lwcf.projectnbr37 = fc_lwcf_grant_points.projectid
AND 
fc_lwcf_grant_boundaries.projectid = tbl_lwcf.projectnbr37
AND 
fc_lwcf_grant_boundaries.rrs_regions = fc_lwcf_rrs_regions.rrs_regions
AND
fc_nc_counties.rrs_regions = fc_lwcf_rrs_regions.rrs_regions
AND
sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants.projectnum = fc_lwcf_grant_points.projectid
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`. `ON`.

Comment: Well, first thing I'd say is, especially with a table name like `sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants` that if you write some chars after a table name it creates an alias for that table that you can then use in the rest of the query. And that query will get a lot nicer if you say `FROM sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants r` and then replace every other use of `whatever.sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants` with `r`, for example: `SELECT r.projectnum, r.projectnumother ... FROM sync_lwcf_annual_inspection_report_for_active_grants r INNER JOIN...`

Comment: What is your actual question? Does your query work? If not, what happens? Do you get too few rows? If so, explain which are missing. Or are there too many rows? Duplicates maybe? The join syntax you are using has been out-dated for almost three centuries. It is surprising to see you are using it. Any recent (well, less than twenty years old actually) tutorial or book should have told you better.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner maybe not 3 *centuries*, but decades I could go for! :)

Comment: @Caius Jard: OMG what a typo. Just watched a science fiction movie; maybe that's why. :D I like your answer by the way. Very thorough.

Comment: I was gonna quip; I know they say "time flies when you're having fun", but you must have the best job on the planet if it has flown that much for you, since ANSI92! :)

Comment: There is no question here. You don't clearly say what you want your query to do or what is wrong etc etc. "Any help" is not an on-topic question. Please for code questions give a [mre]. That includes giving data to illustrate the first subexpression that doesn't give what you expect & what you expect & why you expect it. Also this is not cut & paste & runnable & it has many unnecessary column selects & probably joins. Etc. [ask] [help]

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the mixed advise. As stated I am new to this hence the ask for help. I recognize I do not know what I am doing that's why I asked. I am trying to learn; I am not a DBA nor am I formally trained in SQL. I appreciate those who have left constructive advise. I'm going to try some of this and see where it gets me. -Sincerely the student trying to LEARN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to write a join between Person and Job, bearing in mind that not every person has a Job. It produces a list of all people and for each person who has a job, their job info or all nulls in the job columns if they have no job:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  person p
  LEFT JOIN job j ON p.jobid = j.id
```

It doesn't matter which way round the predicate is (`j.id = p.jobid` is fine)

The left table is defined as the one before the words LEFT JOIN. The left table in a left join is the "solid" table- all its rows that match the where clause will be presented. The right table is the one that is mentioned after the words RIGHT JOIN and is the one that may become sparse/have nulls in all its columns if there is no matching row on the right for the row from the left

Do not write a where clause that then specifies a predicate on the right table because it will cause the nulls to disappear again (left join then behaves like inner join) unless you have a "`or righttable.column is null`" which is needlessly wordy and also needs careful bracketing to work out if there are multiple predicates.

If you need to specify something that restricts the rows in the right table, do it as part of the ON clause instead. Here is an example of a query that finds all 1000 people plus only those 100 job infos where it is a *manualskilled* type of job:

```
--yes, produces all 1000 people and 900 null job infos, 100 manualskilled job infos
SELECT * 
FROM
  person p
  LEFT JOIN job j ON p.jobid = j.id AND j.jobtype ='manualskilled'


--no, produces just 100 rows, 900 people are missing
SELECT * 
FROM
  person p
  LEFT JOIN job j ON p.jobid = j.id
WHERE
  j.jobtype = 'manualskilled'
```

This happens because the NULL in jobtype, introduced by the left join, is removed when compared to the constant string 'manualskilled'. Anything compared to NULL is unknown, which is never true. Things that are not true in a where clause cannot make it into an output result set, as you're finding right now with your query!

Oh, and the last point worth mentioning; be careful when you mix inner, left and right joins as it can have a profound effect on query output. You'll probably get closest to what you're logically expecting if you do all your inner joins first, then your left joins, and if you need to join any tables onto a table you've already left joined then use left join again. Avoid using right joins at all (rewrite them the other way round so they're a left join). If you inner join a table to a table that has been left joined, then rows will disappear again for the same "null cannot be compared to another value and produce a true"

Comment: Left Join did the trick! Thank you for your comments and carefully explained methods.

Comment: No probs. If an answer is the one you end up using, click the grey tick to turn it green- this means other people can see it has an accepted answer from the dashboard. Upvote answers that are also useful to you. Any number of answers can be upvoted but only one can be ticked. Ticked answers can be upvoted also